# SLA of a cloud app using Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, active-directory, cloud, high-availability, azure-ad-b2c

In the [SLA page of Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/legal/sla/active-directory-b2c/v1_0/), it states that the Azure AD B2C is available at least 99.9% of the time.

Does this mean that, if I have a cloud application which uses AD B2C, its availability cannot get better than 99.9%?

How do I improve the app's availability given that AD B2C availability number is 99.9%?

Comment: I guess if you depend on something that has 99.9 SLA, that is your limit. To go beyond it, you would have to make it so your app works even if the dependency does not.

Comment: @juunas , that is true, and I would know how to handle such a situation when such a dependency is a part of my App, by adding redundant paths. But, since AD B2C is from Microsoft and it is used for login, I am kind of lost for options.